# Defining a generic Typescript function that will take unknown parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a custom input component that has an `onChange` method.

```
type CustomInput = {
  dataType: string;
  onChange: (data: Record<string, unknown) => unknown; // this is causing issues, might need generic type
}
```

**Usage:**

```
type MyProp = {
  name: string;
  date: Date;
}

<CustomInput dataType="myPropData" onChange={(prop: MyProp) => { /* do stuff with prop */ }} />
```

Inside of the component, we perform some logic then call `onChange(data)`. `data` will be different based on what `dataType` is passed.

Another usage may be

```
type MyOtherProp = {
  name: string;
  title: string;
  count: number;
}

<CustomInput dataType="myOtherPropData" onChange={(prop: MyOtherProp) => { /* do stuff with other prop */ }} />
```

**Issue:**

Because `MyProp` and `MyOtherProp` are not really `Record<string, unknown>`, I'm getting errors.

It's clear why there are errors and I'm sure the answer is "use generics", but it's unclear to me how I can set the proper type on the `onChange` method. Using `unknown` params also throws errors and I'd like to avoid using `any`.

Comment: What does `CustomInput` do with the `onChange` property? Can you just use `onChange: unknown`? Probably, not you'll want a function to call. What data are you passing, what does it depend on? What are you doing with the return value?

Comment: It's weird. The input takes the `dataType` prop and some other data. When the component changes, it updates data in our store (determined based on `dataType`). So on change the component updates our store, then runs a custom function (the custom `onChange` method) and passes the returned data to it - this `onChange` can be anything. Any component can do anything it wants with the retuned data. So it's very generic. It just means, when this thing changes, update our store, then let me run any method I'd like after the store update.

Comment: But then it should be `() => void`. Or `(input: StoreTypes[DataType]) => void`. But if `CustomInput` changes the store, it probably knows what data it is updating in there, not just anything?

Comment: "it probably knows what data it is updating in there". Sort of. But it can be one of maybe 20 different things. It can be anything, really.

Comment: Who knows it then? How does it know? If it's really anything, then type it as `any`. Or `unknown`, and force the caller to assert the type.

Comment: After going through it, I think I was interpreting this thing wrong. It is a well known type. But back to the original issue - the real issue is that it's expecting any key-value-pair object (Record<string, unknown>). The method will handle anything given to it that looks like that. Sometimes it's a well known type that's a <string, unknown> object (like type Something = { "param1": 1, "param2": 'something' }). In this case, because "Something" isn't specifically a Record<string, unknown>, it threw errors (even though it's essentially a key-value-pair object.

Comment: No, you got the contravariance wrong. While `Something` is a subtype of `Record<string, unknown>`, the function type `(some: Something) => void` is **not** a subtype of `(rec: Record<string, unknown>) => void`. The latter is a function that needs to handle *any* record - because the caller can pass any record - while the former is a function that accepts *only* some things.

Comment: Okay! That makes sense. It's starting to click :) I was able to resolve the problem (I essentially was using the wrong type altogether, making this SO post worthless), but I did learn a bunch here and it all makes sense now - thank you for that. Much appreciated!

Comment: Always glad to help :) You might want to delete the question if you no longer need an answer